# How we call an RPC that not only calls external functions but also updates data structures?

Tags: c++, terminology, binding, rpc

I have a simple C++ RPC that lets you have remote class instances that support live members (data structures) update as well as method calls. For example I had a class declared like this (pseudocode):

```
class Sum{
public:
    RPC_FIELD(int lastSum);
    RPC_METHOD(int summ(int a, int b))
    {
     lastSum = a + b;
     return lastSum;
    }
};
```

On machine `A` I had its instance. On machines `B` and `C` I had created its instances and connected them to machine `A`. So now they actually do all processing on machine `A` but machines `B`, `C` get `lastSum` class field updates automatically (and can subscribe to update event).

How to call (`Nice Name`) such a functionality when we have binding over network done automatically by RPC library? How RPC library creator can announce such feature?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what kind of name you're looking for, but I have called what you're describing by the following in the past (dependent on who required reports/descriptions):

- RAU: Remote Auto-Updates
- RSF: Remotely Synchronised Fields
- CSF: Centrally Synchronised Fields
- AFS: Automatic Field Synchronisation
- SFF: Server Fed Fields
- SUF: Server Updated Fields
- CUF: Centrally Updated Fields

Although if you are looking for a definitive name, I am not entirely sure one exists, if there is I would be happy to find out though.